# How can I use "select" in a Git hook?

Tags: git, shell, githooks

I want to use Git `pre-commit` hook. I've modified the default `pre-commit` file, and my hook works well.

Now I want to add some options in the pre-commit like this code:

```sh
select run in "yes" "no"
do 
case $run in 
 "yes")UnitTest;;
 "no")echo "Ignore Unit Test!";;
 *)echo "other";;
esac
done
```

but when I run `git commit`, the output message is

```
Run the Unit Test Case?
1) yes
2) no
#?
```

The script doesn't leave me any opportunity to enter an option; it looks like the hook exits immediately. I've tried to call `pre-commit` from another script, and it works as expected.

How can I use `select` in a Git hook?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The pre-commit hook is run with stdin redirected (to /dev/null in this case), so your "select" statement tries to read and immediately gets an EOF.  You can work around this by redirecting input:

```
exec < /dev/tty
```

before the `select`, or add `< /dev/tty` after the `done` part.